# Adding Android x86 to GRUB2

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, android

I installed `cm-x86_64-14.1-rc1` in a separate partition.
I already have Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 installed on my laptop.

There are a lot of boot sequences online to add android x86 to GRUB, but either they are for really old builds or I am not being able to modify them for my build correctly.

What should be the boot sequence for `cm-x86_64-14.1-rc1` to add in GRUB? Will it be enough if I put the sequence through GRUB customizer and save it?

Comment: @Fabby It was GRUB related so I thought it would be okay to post here.

Comment: I think it's fine to post here. We have loads of questions about problems booting other systems in dual boot.

Comment: Silly question, but have you run `sudo update-grub` (on Ubuntu)?

Comment: @Zanna yes I did that's not the problem.I just solved the problem and edited my question by stating how I did it.Thanks.

Comment: Jongla: Better to use the box below to self-answer your own question...  (that is allowed here: share knowledge!)  **Also: Close vote and referral to Android Enthusiasts removed**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First type  `sudo gedit /etc/grub.d/40_custom` in a terminal and add this boot sequence to the file.

```
menuentry "Lineage x86" {
  set root='(hdX,Y)'
  linux /cm-x86-14.1-rc1/kernel quiet root=/dev/ram0 androidboot.selinux=permissive acpi_sleep=s3_bios,s3_mode SRC=/cm-x86-14.1-rc1
  initrd /cm-x86-14.1-rc1/initrd.img
}
```

`hdX,Y` here is the name of your partition where Android is installed. My installed partition is `sda9`, so the entry will be `hd0,9`. For `sdb5` the entry would be `hd1,5` and so on.

If you haven't installed cm-x86-14.1-rc1 but some other version, replace the lines containing "cm-x86-14.1-rc1" with your version.

Then save the file and run `sudo update-grub` in terminal.

A new working GRUB menu entry for your new androidx86 should be available at the next boot.

PS: `androidboot.selinux=permissive` is necessary for androidx86 version >=7.0

Comment: Why exactly 40_custom and not 41_custom?.